# active cell find last column in a row vba

Tags: excel, vba

I've got this code that finds a specific cell, and then then makes the active cell one to the right of this.

However, I want to make it so that it finds the cell with apples and bananas in it, and instead makes the active cell the cell in the last used column of the same row as the original found apples and bananas cell is in.

I hope this makes sense and I appreciate any help.

Thanks.

```
Cells.Find(What:="Apples and Banana", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
    xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
    xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by finding the row of the cell with the help of `find` and `.row` and then checking the last column before activating the cell.

```
Option Explicit

    Sub test()

    Dim LastCol As Long
    Dim ABRow As Long
    Dim ABrange As Range

      Set ABrange = Cells.Find(What:="Apples and Banana", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
        xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
        xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    If Not ABrange Is Nothing Then
        ABRow = ABrange.Row
    End If

    LastCol = Cells(ABRow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    Cells(ABRow, LastCol).Activate

End Sub
```

Comment: I wouldn't return the `Row` on the same line as the `FIND` as it will throw an error if nothing is found.  Perform the find to return range object, check that it's not nothing and then get the row number from it.

Comment: thank you so much! After the line: Cells(ABRow, LastCol).Activate, do you know the code for copying that selected cell and pasting it as a value and not with the formula? I am aware of the paste special feature but i am not sure how to copy it correctly after selecting it.

Comment: You re welcome, you don t need to copy paste you can write: `Cells(x,y) = cells(ABRow,LastCol).Value`

Comment: Thank you. I edited the code above to include the additions, but I am not sure across multiple sheets how to avoid the clipboard, and also to copy and  paste as values and not formulas. Dw if not but appreciate it

Comment: I would guess that the answer remains something like: 
`Sheets("xxx").Cells(x,y) = Sheets("Vegetables").cells(ABRow,LastCol).Value`

Comment: thank you!! and where would I place this line of code so it copies from sheet xxx to sheet vegetables?

Comment: From sheet xxx to sheet vegetables it s the other way around: 
`Sheets("Vegetables").Cells(ABRow,LastCol) = Sheets("xxx").cells(x,y).Value`
And you place the line where you want, it just depends when you want to copy paste :)

Comment: More points about the copy paste here at the well known Ozgrid: https://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/SpeedingUpVBACode.htm